# How to compare and get differences of responses in Groovy?

Tags: json, post, groovy, comparison, jenkins-groovy

How to compare and get differences of responses in Groovy?

**RESPONSE_1 OUTPUT**

```
{"entity":[{"employer1":[{"name":"John","age": 23}]}]}]}
```

**RESPONSE_2 OUTPUT**

```
{"entity":[{"employer1":[{"name":"John","age": 23}]}],"employer2":[{"name": "Mike","age": 26}]}]}
```

This one is my code. And it res1Differnce only returns null

```
stage('comparison') {
steps {
  script {
   if (RESPONSE_1 == RESPONSE_2) {
    println("Matched")
   } else {
    println("Does not match")
    def res1Difference = RESPONSE_1.minus(RESPONSE_2)
    def res2Difference = RESPONSE_2.minus(RESPONSE_1)
    echo "${res1Difference}"
    echo "${res2Difference}"
   }
  }
}
}
```

I also tried to parse the RESPONSE_1 and RESPONSE_2 to map then used the .minus() and .remove() and .removeAll(). If .minus() or .removeAll() it returns hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature method: .... If .remove() it returns null.

```
def res1 = readJSON text: RESPONSE_1
def res2 = readJSON text: RESPONSE_2 

res1.each { entry ->
def res2Difference = res2.minus("$entry")
}
echo "${res2Difference}"
```

I also tried this one, same output as the other

```
def res1 = res1.remove{entry -> 
res2.contains("$entry.key:$entry.value")
}
echo "${res1Difference}"
```

Pls help me out how to return the differences of both responses.

Comment: Your `RESPONSE` objects are strings, so when using [minus](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/groovy/groovy_minus.htm) on them it works only when one is contained in another - which is not your case. Instead you probably want to convert the JSON strings to a map using [readJSON](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#readjson-read-json-from-files-in-the-workspace) and then use the map minus function on them to get the diff.

Comment: I tried this one, but it only returned the same as my previous one. But all my curly brackets was replaced by square brackets and removed double quotes.  **else {  def resA = readJSON text: RESPONSE_1
  def resB = readJSON text RESPONSE_2 

  def res1Difference = resA.minus(resB)
  def res2Difference = resB.minus(resA)
}**

Comment: minus() for maps works only for the upper level (not nested) keys - in your case they are the same. yo can iterate over each employer and subtract the nested map inside it.

Comment: Tried to use readJSON then instead of minus i used remove and it returns null. Also tried using .each but wont work

Comment: @monami I've thought about parsing the responses to Map objects and then finding the diff, but the example responses OUTPUTs are not valid JSON. Also if trying to work with strings and find the difference, I see, you have spaces difference, e.g. `"entity": [` and `{"entity":[` even it's logically the same data. So, this data looks too inaccurate to produce some stable results.

Comment: I just edited the json response. It doesnt have spaces sorry for the typo